# How Use images from javascript array in react using filter and map function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a javascript array like this:

```js
const IMGS = [{
    id: 0,
    path: "../img/a1.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    path: "../img/a1-01.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: "../img/a1-02.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    path: "../img/a1-03.jpeg",
  }
]
export default IMGS;
```

There are more images I am just showing few of them,
I need to show all the images in react from this array. The condition is the `image_id` should be `>=18` but `<30`. How can I achieve that?
(I need to know the syntax).

I know I can do it using `filter` or `map` function, actually I'm new to javascript coming from c++, python background. It looks bit confusing to me.  Please help!
This is my react code where  I'm rendering it

```js
<React.Fragment>
      <Jumbotron>
          <img src={background} alt="Not loading"  id="jumbotron-image" className="img-fluid"/>
      </Jumbotron>
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <h1>Trending</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {/*images go here*/}
          </div>
      </div>
  </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const IMGS = [
      {
        id: 0,
        src:require("../img/a1.jpeg"),
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        src: require("../img/a1.jpeg"),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        src:require("../img/a1.jpeg"),
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        src:require("../img/a1.jpeg"),
      },
    ]
    const imgFilter= IMGS.filter((img) => img.id >= 18 && img.id < 30)

     {imgFilter.map(p => {
          return <img key={p.id} src={p.src} />;
        })}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`

```js
const IMGS = [
  {
    id: 0,
    path: "../img/a1.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    path: "../img/a1-01.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: "../img/a1-02.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    path: "../img/a1-03.jpeg",
  },
]

const res = IMGS.filter((img) => img.id >= 18 && img.id < 30)

console.log(res)
```