# How to create a loop in reactjs that reads many images from the database?

Tags: reactjs

I have a code that upload images in database (firebase), now I need call this images from Database and I know I need a loop with `map` but I don't know how to use it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

import { storage } from '../../firebase/firebase'

const Upload = () => {

```
const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null)
const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)


const imageChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setPhoto(event.target.files[0])
}

const fileUploadHandler = () => {

    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`image/${photo.name}`).put(photo);

    uploadTask.on(error => {
        console.log(error);
    },
        () => {
            storage.ref('image').child(photo.name).getDownloadURL()
                .then(url => {
                    setUrl(url)
                })
        }
    )
}

return (
    <div className="upload-box">
        <div className="form-upload">
            <input onChange={imageChangeHandler} type="file" className="upload-input" />
            <button onClick={fileUploadHandler} type="submit" value="Send" className="upload-btn">Upload</button>
            <ul>
                <li >
                    <img width="200px" height="200px" src={url} alt="firebase_uladed_image" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Upload

Comment: this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204355/how-use-images-from-javascript-array-in-react-using-filter-and-map-function/64204438#64204438

Comment: @zahra zamani: actually I have a database and I need fetch data and create loop for display in DOM